# how can I create index for this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `deal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `site` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `time` bigint(13) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `site` (`site`),
  KEY `time` (`time`,`site`)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

sql query:

```
select * from `deal` where time>0 && site=8
```

I create index:`time` for this query,

but why this query always using index: `site`?

```
explain select * from `deal` where time>0 && site=8
```

output:

```
table    type    possible_keys   key    key_len    ref   rows   Extra

deal     ref     site,time       site   4          const 1      Using where
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create composite index `site + time` (yes, order matters).

So delete both indexes `site` and `time` now and create 2:

1. `KEY site (site, time)`
2. `KEY time (time)`

Comment: thanks zerkms, `KEY site (site, time)` can completely replace the `KEY site (site)`? (I also need `select * from deal where site=123`)

Comment: @Zenofo: yes, it is called "leftmost". So with index `a+b+c` you don't need to have indexes `a` and `a+b`, since it covers them with its left part